# R console returns 'inputinputinput', how can I turn this off?

Tags: r, input, console, preferences

Every time I enter anything into the R console I get a 'receipt' line (i.e. inputinputinput; see attached screen shot). I can not figure out how to return this off and find it very annoying. I am using R 2.15.2 GUI 1.53 Leopard build 32-bit. Any ideas how to shut if off?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you say *Every time I enter anything* while your session clearly shows it only happens when you run `scatterplot3d`? Were you not able to notice that yourself or is your log not showing enough cases?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is (I can't reproduce it) but if it only happens with `scatterplot3d` you can try to redefine it with a captured output: `scatterplot3d <- function(...)invisible(capture.output(scatterplot3d::scatterplot3d(...)))`

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior.   But looking at the screenshot I only see that behavior when you're using columns from 'input' as your input to `scatterplot3d`.  Can you provide the output of `sessionInfo()` and `str(input)`?

Comment: @Dason  because I'm an idiot. Sorry for not paying attention.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No worries - I was just wondering if I missed something.

Comment: yes it definitely started when I loaded scatterplot3d and now appears to have resolved itself. I still don't know what happened though. I am  providing a screenshot of the sessionInfo() and str(input) just in case gives any insight.

Comment: and now it back again even when I stopped using scatterplot 3d...screenshot attached. So annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you peek thru the r-sig-mag mailing list archives, you'll find that this was a bug in one release of the R.app GUI.   Grab the latest version --which may be simplest if you go ahead and upgrade to R3.0 -- and this problem will disappear.   The latest R.app version for 2.15.3  works properly, but I forget where to grab it.